# is it possible to split the results of a query in mysql into multiple strings in python?

Tags: python, mysql

```
'''
DB connection
'''

#Query
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT x, y FROM table WHERE ID_table=1;")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
#

a="hello"
b="world"
```

> now I need to compare strin a with x and string b with y
> How can I do it? pls help

Comment: Where is your problem? You have to loop over the result of `fetchall` and in the loop you will nedd to compare `a` with the first value in the resulting tuple and `b` with the second value.

Comment: I did not know you could associate a variable to the field obtained from the query, I found the solution thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchall()` returns a list of results, eg `[(x1, y1), (x2, y2) ...]`  to get to the x and y values you can simply index into this list:

```
for (x, y) in myresult:
   print(a == x)
   print(b == y)
```